# Automation on Multiple Platforms

Tags: ui-automation, browser-automation, seetest

My Client has an application which will be working on Desktop Browsers, Mobile Brosers and as a Native app on both Android and iPad. Currently we as test team propsed using Selenium for Web Automation & Combination of Selenium+ SeeTest for web Browser & Native apps. But issue is we are scripting the flows 3 times owing to 3 different platforms. What would be the best strategy to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid

> we are scripting the flows 3 times owing to 3 different platforms.

by utilizing [Write once, test everywhere](https://books.google.bg/books?id=ZmOZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT273&lpg=PT273&dq=write%20once%20test%20everywhere&source=bl&ots=K_sqKhLroK&sig=_VMNYL3Y5m8pdYPkpSfhVtrd-rE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-z7f576PKAhUCCSwKHZo1CjsQ6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=write%20once%20test%20everywhere&f=false) pattern. The concept centers advantage of shared behavior between multiple implementations of one application. For example it should be possible to purchase a product from your website no matter if user uses desktop, mobile or native application. This is also know as pluggable pattern (and [architecture](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/plugin-architecture/)). It could like this:

[image: Plugin architecture]

Used properly it will give you: foresight (boil down every test case), reusability and simplicity. There are disadvantages as well (but I think there is no escape from those anyway):

- Runtime context switching
- Complex code base

Aiming at full answer here, you can consider the [Test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) concept. It propose separation of all your code into three major concerns ([SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)):

- Execution engine (plugins)
- Tests ([BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development))
- Configuration ([as code](http://www.slideshare.net/DougSeven/devops-practicesconfiguration-as-code))